# Generating random color with button in Angular app

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I am generating random color with a button in Angular app. But with this always adding the value to color variable, so first time it generates a random color but after that always adding six letters to color and it means it is not generating color anymore. So I have to reset color value, but where should I reset the color value?

```
letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
color = '#';

getRandomColor(randomColor) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        this.color += this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
    }
```

---

```
<button (click)="getRandomColor()">Generate random color</button>
<p [ngStyle]="{color: color}">Random color</p>
{{color}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset `this.color` to `#` before adding more hex values to it.

```
getRandomColor(randomColor) {
    this.color = '#'; // <-----------
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        this.color += this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
color = '#';

getRandomColor(randomColor) {
      this.color = "#";
      for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        this.color += this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
    }
```

> this.color = "#";

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sometimes it might be hard to see solution even it is too easy to find out.

Answer (score 1):

before for loop reset the value of color by color = '#'

Answer (score 0):

Right above the loop,

```
 getRandomColor(randomColor) {
          this.color = '#';
          for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.color += this.letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
          }
        }
```